# How to interpret $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ in the integral of conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, density-function, conditional-expectation

$f_X(x)$ gives value of the probability density function of random variable $X$ at point $x$. I am not sure how to wrap my head around $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$; is $Y|X$ still a random variable (sorry for the very basic question, I have not been able to find an answer on Google)?

This confusion comes from me trying to figure out $E_{Y|X}(h) = \int hf_{Y|X}(y|x)dy$. I don't understand why there is no $dx$ in the integral.

Comment: The function $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ is the probability density of $Y$ at some point $y$, conditional on the fact that $X=x$. You can think of the value of $x$ as a parameter of this probability distribution.

Comment: The expectation of $Y$ conditional on $X=x$ is then $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_{Y|X}(y|x)dy$. We don't integrate with respect to $x$ because we have fixed this value.

Comment: This expectation will depend on the value of $x$, say $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)=\phi(x)$ for some function $\phi$. We now define the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$ to be $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)=\phi(X)$, i.e. the same function but with $X$ as a random variable. This conditional expectation is itself a random variable, as it is a function of $X$.

Comment: @DoctorMilt thank you very much for the clear explanation. Does this imply that $E(Y|X) = E_{Y|X}(Y)$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation. Is it from a particular textbook?

Comment: @DoctorMilt It is from the slides of a university lecture; I haven't seen it in the corresponding textbook. If you have not seen it before, I will go ask my professor for a clarification. Thank you!